# Paint two overlaid JLabels

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to paint a JLabel over another.
I override paint() so that a second JLabel is painted after calling super.paint().
However this second JLabel is not painted at all (because it is not showing, I think).
How can I achieve that effect?

```
public class OverlaidJLabel extends JLabel {

    private String upperText;

    public OverlaidJLabel(){

    }

    public void setUpperText(String upperText){
        this.upperText = upperText;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        JLabel upperLabel = new JLabel(upperText);
        upperLabel.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better answers, please show an image of the visual affect that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please see edits to answer and ask if any questions

Answer (score 3):

Some big problems here:

1. You don't want to override paint in this situation but rather paintComponent
2. You never want to create components within a painting method. These methods should be for painting and painting only as you'll be creating components many times (since painting methods can be called many times -- and completely out of your control) when they only should be created once, and you don't want to ever slow painting down since this hampers the perceived responsiveness of your GUI.
3. It makes no sense to create a component that is never added to the GUI, such as your upperLabel. Calling its paint method will achieve absolutely nothing (as you're finding out).
4. In general, you will want to favor composition over inheritance.

Much better:

- If you want to have text on top of text, you could create two JLabels (separately), and place them on top of each other using an appropriate layout manager or using a JLayeredPane.
- Or you can do your painting and your painting overlay in a single component, likely the paintComponent override of a JPanel.

For example, one possible overly can use a JLayeredPane that holds two JLabels. A simple example below uses JLabels that hold only text, although you could also implement with ImageIcons, and allow changing each JLabel's font, foreground color, etc...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyLabel extends JLayeredPane {
    // labels to hold texts. label1 is the lower label
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

    public MyLabel(String text1, String text2) {

        // just so I can see the text separately:
        label2.setForeground(Color.RED);

        // set text
        label1.setText(text1);
        label2.setText(text2);

        // JPanels to hold the labels. GridBagLayout will center the labels
        JPanel baseComponent1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel baseComponent2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        // add labels to the JPanels
        baseComponent1.add(label1);
        baseComponent2.add(label2);

        // have to be able to see through the JPanels
        baseComponent1.setOpaque(false);
        baseComponent2.setOpaque(false);

        // add to the JLayeredPane label2 above label1
        add(baseComponent1, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        add(baseComponent2, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

        // If the overall component resizes, resize the 
        // container base JPanels
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                baseComponent1.setSize(MyLabel.this.getSize());
                baseComponent2.setSize(MyLabel.this.getSize());
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    // preferred size depends on the largest dimensions
    // of the two JLabels
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension size1 = label1.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size2 = label2.getPreferredSize();
        int w = Math.max(size1.width, size2.width);
        int h = Math.max(size1.height, size2.height);
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }
}
```

and it can be tested like so:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyLabelTest extends JPanel {
    public MyLabelTest() {
        add(new MyLabel("Test .............................. String 1", "Number 2"));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyLabelTest mainPanel = new MyLabelTest();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyLabelTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

My next iteration would be to add mutator methods to MyLabel to allow changing font, text, and foreground:

```
    public void setFont1(Font font) {
        label1.setFont(font);
    }

    public void setFont2(Font font) {
        label2.setFont(font);
    }

    public void setText1(String text) {
        label1.setText(text);
    }

    public void setText2(String text) {
        label2.setText(text);
    }

    public void setForeground1(Color fg) {
        label1.setForeground(fg);
    }

    public void setForeground2(Color fg) {
        label2.setForeground(fg);
    }
```